# How to use the varchar data type in c#?

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code and I want to make it varchar not string. What is the appropriate syntax to do that in c#

```
 string emri = row["Nome"].ToString();
```

I have a query that I have to run and I use emri in it and compare it with a column in table which I have created in mysql. the column in mysql is of type varchar(20). When I execute my code it gives an error in my query and I was guessing maybe it was for this reason

```
I have this query 
string query = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE CodCliente=   " + id + "  AND Nome = '" + emri + "' AND RagioneSociale=' " + ragSoc + " ' AND PartitaIVA=' " + piva + " ') INSERT INTO clienti VALUES(" + id + " ,' " + emri + " ',' " + ragSoc + " ',' " + piva + " ') else UPDATE clienti SET( " + id + " ,' " + emri + " ',' " + ragSoc + " ',' " + piva + " ')";
```

and it gives me this problem

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE CodCliente=   1  AND NomeCliente = 'Jo' at line 1
```

Comment: What do you mean? There is no type in .NET named "varchar" or similar, the equivalent type is `string`.

Comment: What you have above is fine.  When taking varchar, nvarchar, etc. values that you want to use, the string variable type in .NET is perfect.  If you give more detailed comments about what you want to do, perhaps we can get you a better answer.

Comment: @sammy_winter I edited the content of my question.

Answer (score 18):

There is no `varchar` type in C#.

A `varchar` is pretty much a string (of variable length in SQL, obviously), so what you have is fine.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET there is no type named "varchar", the closest thing you got is `string`.

I'm assuming there is a reason you're asking, and I'm guessing you're having some problems with the code you've posted in the question, so let me try to guess what that is, and tell you how to solve it.

First, since `varchar` doesn't exist, the code as you've posted it looks fine, *on the surface*.

However, there is a problem, you don't show what `row` is, but if it is one of the usual culprits, you're going to run into problems with `null` marks from the database.

A `null` mark in the database in the corresponding column will not be returned as `null` to your .NET code, instead you're going to get back a [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) value.

Here's what I would write instead:

```
string emri;
if (row["Nome"] == DBNull.Value)
    emri = null; // or String.Empty if you don't like null values
else
    emri = Convert.ToString(row["Nome"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

NO this is untrue, When you step through a process by changing the debugging settings located in VS you can step through a SQL script process also if you run an example like this where a table has varchar values set into it.

```
Try
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(examplestring, connection))
  {
    cmd.ExecutenonQuery();
  }
 }
 catch
 {
    return;
  }
```

now put a breakpoint onto the catch statement and in the examplestring  have a string called '456789 - 1' equal to Itemnumber varchar(25) in the SQL table.

The catch will get the following error SqlException was caught - Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Now query string is set as a string cause that is the only way the SqlCommand works look it up on MSDN : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

So yes Lasse there is varchar in .NET.