# How to read the date that is return from a stored procedure which have no parameter using asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_currentDate]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 
END
```

This is my stored procedure code. I got the correct date, but I am unable to read the values in asp.net.

```
public DateTime getCurrentDate()
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dt;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        SqlConnection objSqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "usp_currentDate";
        cmd.Connection = objSqlConn;

        objSqlConn.Open();
        me(1);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt = reader.GetDateTime(1);  
        return dt;  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

but it's not working. It throws an exception

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

What changes do I have to make?

Comment: You should think about using output parameter in your SP.

Comment: I have modified the query as you said but it also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, using `ExecuteScalar` to fetch a single row / single column value:

```
public DateTime getCurrentDate()
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dt;

        // set up connection and command in *using* blocks
        using (SqlConnection objSqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_currentDate", objSqlConn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            objSqlConn.Open();

            // since the query returns exactly one row, one column -> use ExecuteScalar
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            // if something was returned .....
            if (result != null)
            {
                // try to convert to DateTime
                if (DateTime.TryParse(result.ToString(), out dt)
                {
                    return dt;
                }
            }

            // return default value, if no data was read or could not be converted 
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you So much . It worked me.I have edited code like this,     object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                dt = Convert.ToDateTime(result);
                return dt;

Answer (score 0):

Besides on why you return local time with `GETDATE` as a character, you can't read the data reader without move the cursor to it's first line with [`Read` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From documentation;

> The default position of the `SqlDataReader` is before the first record.
>   Therefore, you must call `Read` to begin accessing any data.

```
string s;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.Read())
   s = reader.GetString(0);
```

Or better, use [`ExecuteScalar` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since you return one row with one column like;

```
string s = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Remember, `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)` returns `varchar` which is [preferable used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16112982/447156) with `string` in CLR side, that's why you can't assign this value to a `DateTime` variable.

Also use `using` statement to dispose your database connections and commands.

Comment: ExecuteScalar cannot be used to return a DateTime.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime' in DataAccessLayer this is the exception when i use